# Xamarin Picker binding to a different model property

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms, picker

Hi I have a Xamarin forms application that uses a picker control. its bound to a list of the following

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<MyType> Types { get; set; }
```

...

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

}
```

...

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Type{ get; set; }
}
```

...

```
<Picker x:Name="TypePicker"  Title="Please select a type.."
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyType}, Mode=TwoWay}"  
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Description}"  
    SelectedItem="{Binding Contact.Type}" />
```

I'm wondering how to store and set the value of the picker control (Code) which is a string, into the {Binding Contact.Type} SelectedItem

I've seen examples:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/102876/how-to-get-selected-value-from-binding-picker

But this doesn't update a different type from what the picker uses.

Comment: You mean you want to reflect the value of picker's selected item(Code property) into another binding property?

Comment: In order to set a picker's SelectedItem binding to a desired item, first that item needs to be of the same model, and second, it must already be one of that Picker's ItemSourse collection items.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Yes the two objects are part of the same model. The lookup object is bound to the picker object. The other object (Contact) has the property which I want to store the value.

Comment: What does "Types" look like ? and Contact.Details.Type does not exist, you only have Contact.Type (based on the given code)

Comment: sorry, Types was meant to be MyType, I've updated the question

Comment: @the_tr00per Did you solve the problem? I got exact one and stack on it :/